# Flirting Sequences, Convergence (Real Analysis)

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Can anyone provide some insight or help into the following problem?

Definition: In a metric space, a sequence ${p_n}$ **flirts** with $p$ iff for each $\epsilon > 0$ there are $m,n \in \mathbb{N}$ where $m>n$ such that $0<d(p_n, p) < \epsilon$ and $d(p_n,p) < d(p_m,p)$.

Problem: If a sequence ${p_n}$ flirts with each point in a sequence ${q_n}$ and $q_n$ converges to $q$, does ${p_n}$ flirt with $q$? Prove it.

I wrote out the definitions for "${p_n}$ flirts with each point in a sequence ${q_n}$" and for "$q_n$ converges to $q$. I also wrote out the definition for "${p_n}$ flirt with $q$". I've been staring at them, trying to manipulate the first two so that they work for the third definition, but am stuck. I am not even sure how to proceed. Any help in trying to solve this problem will be helpful!

For reference, you can check [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3038605/flirting-sequences-real-analysis) for examples of flirting sequences.

By the way... I think the answer is no, but its more of intuition than anything.

Answer (score 1):

If there is an $n$ such that $q_n = q$, then it immediately follows that $(p_n)$ flirts with $q$.

Thus we need only care about the case $q_n \neq q$ for all $n$.

Let $\epsilon > 0$ be given. Choose an arbitrary $k$. Let $\delta = \frac{1}{3}d(q_k,q)$ and $\eta = \min \{\epsilon/2, \delta\}$. Since $q_n \to q$ there is an $r$ with $d(q_r,q) < \eta$. Since $(p_n)$ flirts with $q_r$ there is an $n$ with $0 < d(p_n,q_r) < d(q_r,q) < \eta$, and consequently $0 < d(p_n,q) < 2\eta < \epsilon$. It now suffices to show that there is an $m > n$ with $d(p_m,q_k) < \eta$, for then
$$d(p_m,q) \geqslant d(q_k,q) - d(p_m,q_k) > d(q_k,q) - \eta = 3\delta - \eta \geqslant 2\eta > d(p_n,q)$$
shows that $(p_n)$ flirts with $q$.

But there are only finitely many indices $\leqslant n$, thus
$$\lambda = \min \:(\{ d(p_s,q_k) : s \leqslant n, p_s \neq q_k\} \cup \{\eta\}) > 0,$$
and the flirting of $(p_n)$ with $q_k$ yields the existence of an $m$ with $0 < d(p_m,q_k) < \lambda \leqslant \eta$. This $m$ is $> n$ by construction.

Answer (score 0):

This is easier than you think.
Since $p_n$ flirts with each $q_n$ then you have that $d(p_n,q_n)\to 0$. 
Because you are given $q_n\to q$, we have $||q_n-q||$ converges to 0. By the triangle inequality you obtain that 
$d(p_n,q)\le d(p_n,q_n)+  ||q_n-q||$ therefore $d(p_n,q)<\epsilon$ right away. Hence the sequence $p_n$ actually converges to $q$.

Finally the fact $d(p_n,q)<d(p_m,q)$ comes from the fact that the sequence converges hence the distance is getting smaller and smaller, therefore
We can esasily find an $n,m$ with $d(p_n,q)<d(p_m,q)$ by arguing that as $n$ approaches to $\infty$, by the Archimedean Principle, such $n$ exists.

This was easier than we thought!  I love this stuff!